# CSS text-overflow as ellipsis not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm with a simple problem with `text-overflow`.
I can `ellipsis` my text, but the text won't fill the div entirely.

Here's the demo in jsfiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4FKm/)

I thought that this piece of code would do the trick but I'm wrong.

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

I've seen various topics related like [CSS text ellipsis when using variable width divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649904/css-text-ellipsis-when-using-variable-width-divs), [Can't get "text-overflow: ellipsis;" to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555398/cant-get-text-overflow-ellipsis-to-work), but none of them worked for me.

Comment: This is expected behaviour, text-overflow doesnt work on a vertical basis, only on a line of horizontal content - you'll need a JS solution

Comment: Thanks, I've searched a bit and you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add width to the element for ellipsis to work.
It works when content exceed the width of the container. It would not work without specifying the width of the container.

Comment: I've added `width: 300px;` to both `div` and `p` and it does not seem to work.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, I added the width to p:first, and got the desired response. Try the same, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manublueheart/D4FKm/3/

The trick is adding `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;` to your css

```
p.first{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    line-height: 16px;     /* fallback */
    max-height: 32px;      /* fallback */
}
```